# 'ld: file not found' after changing product name in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6, linker-errors

I was working on my application and i started out with a really bad name. So i decided to change it. I did that like this.

[image]

At the top right corner i simply changed the name to what i want. and then i started getting the error as you can see there. *Reveal in Log* shows these details:

[image]

The main error says:

> ld: file not found: /Users/.../XCode/DerivedData/...

Comment: did you try to clean and rebuild?

Comment: Yes, tried closing Xcode etc all that

Comment: I changed the project name and it compiled fine. At the worst situation you may need to recreate project and import your code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go to edit scheme as shown below.
[image]

then uncheck all other targets except your main target under build tab.
[image]

Comment: this actually worked. But what does that mean when i did that? Is there a negative effect from this?

Comment: Cannot explain it here hamzah as even I dont have clear idea regarding the negative effect..but as per stack overflow rules..if the above answer solved your problem , u can mark it as the correct answer which would earn both of us some reputation points..cheers!!

Comment: @Alyoshak : Is the issue same as mentioned here?

Comment: I additionally had to do `pod install`, now it works fine again

Comment: I had the same issue, i did this, reinstalled node mods and did a pod install after the steps above

Answer (score 12):

I recently got this error under different circumstances.  Running Ionic, updating my ios platform from 3.8.0 to 4.0.1 I discovered this error.

I had to disable bitcode in my app.

To do this, click your top level app icon in the file structure. In the main window, click the header build settings.  In the search bar, type bit (or bitcode) and you should see enable bit code beneath

I had disabled it before, but I'm guessing that updating the ios platform enables bitcode so it needed to be disabled again.

Comment: You deserve more for this answer. Thanks! worked for me

Answer (score 4):

No need to mess with schemes. Just go to build settings for your targets or project and turn off Bitcode.

[image]

Comment: You stated "go to build settings for your targets" but in your picture, you're not in one of your targets- you're in your project itself (listed above the list of targets).  Unfortunately, neither one worked for me.  Regardless, I suggest you revise your answer to state where your screenshot actually is.

Comment: It's the same bitcode option. You can choose your target or project. There are many solutions to one problem. Some may work for you some may work for others. Obviously it worked for whoever up-voted my answer. Apparently your issue needs a different solution.

Comment: Yes, but I'm pointing out that your text and your screenshot don't match- which is misleading!

Comment: I added the word "project" for you :)

Answer (score 4):

### Real Issue

After changing the `PRODUCT_NAME` (as seen in the question) the erroneous reference to **Host Application** is the real cause of the issue.

Just select your Tests-Target and under the General-Tab select your updated Host Application.

Afterwards, building the project will work.

[image: Tests Host Application]

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by Deleting the Derived Data and rebuilding the project.

1. Go to Windows > Projects
2. Select Your Project
3. Delete Derived Data
4. Build your project and Run

Answer (score 0):

If you see this error without detail result then check 'enum' in header file. Move them in .m file.

Answer (score -2):

By deleting the derived data Xcode will recompile and regenerate the data for you.

You can do that by going to:
Windows -> projects
Delete derived data

Comment: There is no such option (Projects) under _Window_ menu in Xcode 8.3.